# How to log ssl handshake failures in the access_log in nginx?

Tags: ssl, nginx

I'm trying to keep track of how many handshake failures are occurring in nginx.

In 1.2, my access log used to have entries where most of the fields were blank, my understanding is that they were dummy requests generated when an ssl handshake had failed.

My current access_log doesn't have those now using 1.6. Is there any way to get them enabled?

And yes, I can see the entries in the error log, but that's no use for metric reporting.